# C чем связано снижение производительности приложений, написанных на Java?

Tags: java

Привет всем!

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Я не особо силен в таких тонкостях, поэтому прошу тут помощи. В чем же проблема? Это связано с высокоуровневостью языка? С тем, что в приложение  дописывается куча каких-то дополнительных проверок? С тем, что типы данных "не легкие"?

Заранее благодарен за ответы. )

Comment: а кривизну рук не рассматриваете?)

Comment: Забавный вброс.

Comment: Рассматриваю, но можно посерьезней?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если Вы серьезно, то насколько я понял Вы спрашиваете почему Java медленнее С/С++ работает ?
Если Вы это и имели ввиду, тогда давайте по порядку.

Во-первых языки бывают компилируемые и интерпретируемые. Java является интерпретируемым(если не вдаваться во все тонкости). Чтобы не повторяться по поводу определений позаимствую из просторов интернета.

> Программа на компилируемом языке при
> помощи специальной программы
> компилятора преобразуется
> (компилируется) в набор инструкций для
> данного типа процессора (машинный код)
> и далее записывается в исполняемый
> файл, который может быть запущен на
> выполнение как отдельная программа.
> Другими словами, компилятор переводит
> программу с языка высокого уровня на
> низкоуровневый язык, понятный
> процессору.
>
> Если программа написана на
> интерпретируемом языке, то
> интерпретатор непосредственно
> выполняет (интерпретирует) ее текст
> без предварительного перевода. При
> этом программа остается на исходном
> языке и не может быть запущена без
> интерпретатора. Можно сказать, что
> процессор компьютера — это
> интерпретатор машинного кода.

Думаю здесь все понятно должно быть.

1. Есть такое понятие как виртуальная машина. Это абстракция которая по сути эмитирует реальный компьютер. В ней тоже есть основные узлы такие как управления памятью, потоками... Можете считать что это компьютер в компьютере. Такие машины обычно пишутся на языках низкого уровня для достижения быстродействия.
2. Возьмем за основу Java Virtual Machine Hotspot. Это "программа" написанная на языке С++. Она предоставляет собой набор различных компонентов (Execution Engine, JIT, Class Loader). Можете об этом почитать в интернете. Можете запустить любое приложение на Java и увидите что у Вас в процессах висит процесс Java (jvm запущенный с определенными ключами).Это и есть инстанс Вашей JVM.
3. Язык. Java в данном случае. Высокоуровневые языки придумали не для компьютера, а для человека. Для того чтобы можно было быстро реализовать задачи бизнес приложений. Не будете же Вы на ассемблере писать код для такого рода задач. Еще одним преимуществом есть читабельность. Если код хорошо написанный, то его можно читать как книгу, без избыточности конструкций определенного языка. Все внутренне сложности,связь с железом инкапсулированы внутри реализации виртуальной машины. Вам предоставлен интерфейс, если можно так сказать.
4. Программа на таких языках компилируется не в машинный код определенной архитектуры, а в промежуточный, так называем байт код, который затем уже интерпретируется.
5. В JVM Hotspot присутствует множество оптимизаций по улучшению быстродействия,например, динамическая компиляции JIT и адаптивная оптимизация.

В чем же преимущество таких языков ?
В том что Вы пишете такой код, который будет работать на любой машине где есть установленная ВМ(JVM в данном случае).Вам не нужно знать какие инструкции поддерживает та или иная архитектура процессора и другие мелочи.

Ну и собственно ответ на Ваш вопрос. 
Проигрыш в быстродействии относительно компилируемых языков в том, что вводятся дополнительные уровни абстракции(виртуальные машины). В данном случае. Исполняемый код для определенной архитектуры Вам выдает интерпретатор.

**EDIT**

Дополнение по поводу Android

Если брать Android Dalvik VM. То тут все практически также как и Java VM. Написанием Dalvik VM для определенной архитектуры занимается разработчик данной архитектуры или же производитель телефонов. При наличии достаточных аппаратных средств Вы можете написать свою виртуальную машину для холодильника ,микроволновки, стиралки (кстати такое можно встретить). 
По поводу нативных модулей. В Java присутствует такой механизм под названием JNI (Java Native Interface). Это интерфейс для связи с нативным кодом( написанным на Assembler, C++,C ..) из Java. Примером может служить тот же hashCode метод в классе Object, там стоит ключевое слово native. То есть данный метод будет вызываться из библиотеки скомпилированной нативными компиляторами с помощью интерфейса JNI.
В таких случаях такой код Вы компилируете с помощью нативных компиляторов. Например, для Андроида Вы создаете make-файл, который служит для компилятора нативного кода. Кстати, для Андроида существует обертка утилиты GNU make и имеет название **ndk-build** . Он в свою очередь вызывает компилятор g++/gcc заточенный под архитектуры используемые на устройствах вот пример Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE := test
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp 
    LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x -Wall         # whatever g++ flags you like
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog   # whatever ld flags you like

    include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)    # <-- Use this to build an executable.
```

Еще существует файл для задания архитектур для которых нужно скомпилировать выполняемый файл. Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all // Для всех архитектур
```

Это если кратко. Тут очень много чего можно изучать, но как говориться, это уже другая история.

Comment: Спасибо, именно это и имел ввиду) Хорошо, возник еще вопрос) Вы говорите что программа для компьютера компилируется в байт-код, ок, про это я слышал. Я абсолютно не могу понять по такому же принципу или нет собираются и работают программы на мобильных устройствах под Android???

Comment: @Alerr, да, всё именно так. На Android стоит виртуальная машина Dalvik, в байт-код которой компилируются все программы для Android, написанные на Java. Это позволяет не беспокоиться об аппаратной части устройства и запускать одну и ту же Java программу на любых устройствах. Чуть сложнее с программами, использующими нативные модули, их приходится компилировать отдельно для каждой архитектуры процессора.

Comment: Спасибо, что вы имеете ввиду под нативными модулями? Можете привести пример?

Comment: @Alerr, под Android требовательные к производительности операции можно вынести в нативные модули, написанные на C и исполняющиеся непосредственно на процессоре устройства. Например, хитрая отрисовка графики или декодирование видео.

Answer (score 2):

> Рассматриваю, но можно посерьезней?)

как раз-таки это и был самый серьезный вариант. В 99,9% случаев проблемы с производительностью - это именно вопрос кривизны рук разработчика. Сам язык и платформа за 20 лет своей истории были оптимизированы настолько, насколько это возможно, и грещшить на них в вопросе производительности чаще всего не стоит

Comment: @DreamChild, видимо сложившаяся практика программирования на Java просто притягивает туда криворуких.

На практике-то, пользователи частенько ругаются на тормоза серверных приложений на Java при росте нагрузки.  

(конечно, проверить, что виновата тут именно Java, из-за отсутствия аналога на других языках не удастся)

Answer (score 1):

Встречный вопрос: что конкретно подразумевается под снижением производительности? Прогресс бар медленнее бегает? Файлы долго читаются? Запрос по сети отрабатывает дольше?

Общий ответ - да, в любом высокоуровневом языке в среднем производится больше операций, чем в низкоуровневых. Однако, как правило, это незаметно для пользователя, экономит время разработки и вносит куда меньший impact, чем прорубленная молотком архитектура.